# Sqlite returns 0 rows if I use WHERE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem with Sqlite.

This is structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "data"(
"_id" Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"correct" Text,
"id_topic" Integer,
"id_unique" Integer,
"picture" Text,
"question" Text,
"used" Integer DEFAULT 0,
"wrong1" Text,
"wrong2" Text,
"wrong3" Text,
"lang" Text );
```

If I run this SQL query I get 0 rows even though I have rows in table that have id_topic = 1

```
SELECT _id, question, picture, correct, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, id_topic, id_unique, used 
FROM data
WHERE id_topic = 1
ORDER BY used, RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

If I remove WHERE from query everything works fine and I can get rows where id_topic = 1 without a problem.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you have no rows where `id_topic = 1`.  You may think you do, but you don't.

Comment: Please show us your code! Maybe the problem is not the statement

Comment: @GordonLinoff as I said I do have rows with id_topic = 1 as I can see the data in SQLite editor where I also run the query.

Comment: @Jens I'm running query in SQLite editor and it doesn't work even there.

Comment: Try it without the Order By and Limit clauses; see if you get any data then.

Comment: Where do these values come from? Written by some program? Import?

Comment: @simonatrcl unfortunately 0 rows even without ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: @CL. all data was manually written and then imported as CSV.

Comment: @Ryx5 It doesn't work.

Comment: Try with a `FROM data as d` and also with **`** backquote between table and fields labels

Comment: @Ryx5 nope, still doesn't work

Comment: @DerGolem ORDER BY is not the problem as query works fine without WHERE

Comment: @Soriyyx: can you post the relevant output from the Statement whithout where clause?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the query as follows (with WHERE clause but without order by and following block). 
For example:

```
SELECT _id, question, picture, correct, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, id_topic, id_unique, used 
FROM data
WHERE id_topic = 1
```